# How do I keep the keyboard permanently on screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following component in my SwiftUI app:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var search = Search()
   
    @FocusState private var fieldIsFocused: Bool
    
    @State private var word: String = ""
    var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(word).font(.title2)
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    TextField(
                        "Search ...",
                        text: $word
                    )
                        .autocorrectionDisabled()
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .onSubmit {
                            fieldIsFocused = true
                        }
                        .focused($fieldIsFocused)
                        .onAppear {
                            fieldIsFocused = true
                        }
                }
                .padding()

                        
            }
}
```

I want the keyboard to remain on screen at all times. Ie, for the text field to always be focused. I can sort of achieve this by setting `fieldIsFocused` to true when the field appears and is submitted, but it leads to janky animations where the keyboard starts to slide down, then pops back up. I'm looking for a cleaner solution to persist the keyboard at all times.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I came up with just SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var word = ""
    @StateObject var textHolder = TextHolder()
    @FocusState var fieldIsFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(word).font(.title2)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                TextField("Search ...", text: $textHolder.text)
                    .autocorrectionDisabled()
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .keyboardType(.twitter)
                    .focused($fieldIsFocused)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            fieldIsFocused = true
            textHolder.onSubmit = { word = textHolder.text }
        }
    }
    
    final class TextHolder: ObservableObject {
        @Published private var _text = ""
        
        var text: String {
            get { _text }
            set {
                _text = String(newValue.filter { $0 != "#" })
                if newValue.contains(where: { $0 == "#" }) {
                    onSubmit()
                }
            }
        }
        var onSubmit = {}
    }
}
```

Based on what Apple provides, the only time keyboard doesn't hide on return key is when keyboardType == .twitter. But now we need to avoid hashtags and execute submit when there is a hashtag. That's what TextHolder does.
Keep in mind that whenever user types '#', it will trigger submit

Comment: not a bad solution, but unfortunately pressing the "return" button is still hiding the keyboard when I test this, and I'd prefer the return/search button remain near the letters, not numbers.

Comment: @pwasoutside but there is no 'return' button. It's replaced with '#'. What is your minimum deployment?